# Should I use data for autocomplete from xml files directly or upload to GAE datastore?

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've found [another source](http://translate.google.ru/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/DownloadPage.aspx) of data to [implement autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757568/how-to-upload-data-from-dbf-files-to-gae-datastore) for addresses input in my form.

The data is stored in xml files ([data structure description](http://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=ru&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/Docs/%25D0%25A1%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B5%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%2520%25D0%25BE%2520%25D1%2581%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B5%2520%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D1%2584%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B0%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B8%2520%25D0%25A4%25D0%2598%25D0%2590%25D0%25A1.doc), please refer to page 44).

Should I use xml files directly? Or should I upload all data into GAE datastore (is there any tool to do it)?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost certainly going to run in to some performance problems if you have an auto-complete call that is loading, parsing and searching a large XML file each time. That's going to kill you under any kind of a load at all.

Depending on how much data you are talking about, you could store it all in memcache to give you the very best performance characteristics.

If you are talking about more data than you can sensible store in memcache -- if I recall correctly, it'll keep about 1Mb at a time for you -- you would probably want to store it in the datastore in a structure that is highly-optimized for fast queries.

Comment: If the data is of reasonable size, it would make more sense to store it in instance memory than memcache.

Comment: Nick, since you have more insight into AE's internal working than most of us, could you give us a quick swag at what 'reasonable' is for instance memory, memcache, the datastore?

Comment: And @LA_, as a followup, how much data are you dealing with here?

Comment: A standard [frontend instance](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings.html) has 128MB memory; larger ones have 256 or 512MB. How much of that you can afford to dedicate to static data depends on what you're doing with your app. Memcache is best used for dynamic data, because it's slower than local instance memory, but provides global consistency. The datastore is slower again, but has no size limits, and is persistent. Basically, if you have static data, store it in local memory if you can, and on local disk if you can't.

Comment: I just recalled, I wrote [a post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/11/Storage-options-on-App-Engine) about this a while ago that's relevant.

Comment: @AdamCrossland, addresses database is about 700Mb, if I recall it correctly.